# Why don't all bugs and feature-requests have moderator status tags?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, meta

I'm not too familiar with status-tracking in general, but it seems tags exist to cover all states of these questions: -deferred, -bydesign, -planned, -declined, -completed, -review; -norepro, -reproduced.  Yet not every feature-request or bug question has one of these collectively inclusive tags.

So... why not?  Is it just a matter of convenience?  What does the default state of having no status tag mean?  That it is just a bad question?  Or that there's no consensus yet?

Comment: Make me a mod and I will gladly review all of these, possibly adding `status-noonecares` where appropriate :P

Comment: This does seem to simply be an issue of not enough moderators.  Even a *bad* request deserves attention to be officially declined.

Comment: see also: [Why don't we get responses from bug reports?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186803/why-dont-we-get-responses-from-bug-reports)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> bug × 2081
> feature-request × 3907

The numbers tell the story.

Take any average bug or issue tracking system on a public project -- how many of these bugs/features have a status other than "no action"?

The reality is that there are far too many incoming requests for us to process every one.

If your bug or feature request gets a lot of votes, or is urgent in some other obvious way, it will be handled. Otherwise, you need to rally support for your request by convincing other users in the community (and, by proxy, us) it's worth doing.

See the "bugs" and "reqs" tabs on the homepage:
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/new-top-bugs-and-top-requests-on-meta/

Answer (score 10):

All feature requests and bugs are effectively "status pending" by default.

It then goes to the team to decide its ultimate fate with any one of the status tags as it graduates to a finality of:

- **planned/review** - they're in the works and logistics and logic are actively being worked on.
- **deferred** - down the pipelines or dependent on a third-party, such is the case with many of the prettify bug reports or syntax highlighting changes.
- **declined** - the death bong, a stirring ring of "no" or "not in this form".
- **completed** - the request or bug squash has been fulfilled and the pants have been unbuckled for the gut to hangeth over.

Sometimes they just slip on by and will rise again.

Comment: With terms like “death bong” and “pants have been unbuckled”, how could I not vote this up?

Answer (score 3):

It might mean any of the following:

"We haven't looked at this yet",
"We've reproduced and we're working on a fix" - Not long-term enough for `[status-reproduced]`,
"We've given it some light thought and aren't sure yet or have made a tentative decision",

To contrast, `[status-review]` means more of a "We're having serious discussion internally about this."