# Review top voted feature-requests with status-declined

Tags: feature-request, review, declined-flags

There are many feature-requests with "status-declined" https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-declined
 or "by design", that have high number of votes.

**They should be considered for review if the number of votes exceed some limit(e.g. 25) and status was changed some time (e.g. 1 year) ago.**

Jeff Atwood' s suggestion in [the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/new-top-bugs-and-top-requests-on-meta) comment May 14 2010

> If you want [status-declined] / [status-bydesign] items to be
> reconsidered, you should open them as new requests, link to the old
> request, and explain in a VERY convincing way why “this time is
> different” :)

is not realistic. 
Most likely the new request will be closed as a duplicate. And how long it would take for the new request to get reasonable number of votes, that old request already have?

Currently any votes for declined/bydesign questions are ignored.
This is contradicts to [Jeff' s recommendation](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/new-top-bugs-and-top-requests-on-meta/)

> if your favorite isn’t there,search for it and vote it up to get it on
> that meta leaderboard, and on our radar.

The review process will be consistent with [the normal approach](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60519/163139)

> If your bug or feature request gets a lot of votes, or is urgent in
> some other obvious way, it will be handled. Otherwise, you need to
> rally support for your request by convincing other users in the
> community (and, by proxy, us) it's worth doing.

Comment: Is the insulting sarcasm necessary? I generally agreed with the proposal up until that point.

Comment: @DavidRobinson, thanks, I removed "sarcasm" statement

Answer (score 2):

*Why* is it "not realistic"? I think it's perfectly realistic and is exactly the formula I stick to when deciding whether to vote to close as a duplicate.

When a feature request is declined, it's done for a reason. That reason may be valid or invalid but either way you have to come up with a convincing argument against it. If you fail to come up with a convincing argument that debunks the decline reason why on earth should the decline reason be reconsidered?

You don't have to put it in a separate question, you can add it as an additional answer to the original request. You'll be surprised how often upvotes come pouring in to a newly bumped question or to a well-thought-out feature request.

Yes, there are some feature requests that have been declined, where there's a constant stream of questions being closed as a duplicate of it, [*cough*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted). However, this particular question, and others like it, are the elephant in the room. Everyone knows it's there; because of the constant stream of duplicates it gets regularly bumped and it is massively upvoted. Parts of the request have now [been implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/turbocharging-the-roomba-solutions-for-premature-deletion); if we all keep plugging away maybe more will be in the future.

#### tl;dr

I think the system works. If you don't have anything to add, but support the request, then upvote it! If you have something to add then please do so, anything that gets a great feature request implemented would be wonderful. As for re-evaluating, it's done on a daily basis by the community. If a request has enough support everyone is already more than aware of its existence.

Comment: * cough * preemptive-reopening / retracting close-votes * cough *