# What is "a lot of votes" in regards to feature-request tagged questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, community

In [Jeff Atwood's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60519/187194) on [Why don't all bugs and feature-requests have moderator status tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60505/why-dont-all-bugs-and-feature-requests-have-moderator-status-tags?lq=1):

> If your bug or feature request gets a lot of votes, or is urgent in
>   some other obvious way, it will be handled. Otherwise, you need to
>   rally support for your request by convincing other users in the
>   community (and, by proxy, us) it's worth doing.

Often times, when browsing this site, I see many feature-request tagged questions that receive "many" upvotes, ranging from 50-250 with no `status-declined` tag or `status-bydesign` or any of the other `status` tags.  There are some good proposals out there....but with what seems like no interest on SE's part, and no tag to show the status.

What did Jeff Atwood mean in this context? What represents "a lot of votes"?  It's not uncommon to see `status` tagged feature-reqs with sub-100 upvotes, so what are "a lot of votes" in the context he provided?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263662/can-we-have-a-guaranteed-pipeline-for-responses-from-stack-exchange for an attempt at formalizing this at a particular threshold, and the reasons such a threshold does not exist.